# Is it possible to use MS Java EWS to search for all mailboxes on server?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are building an archival system where we require the Conversation History contents of all mailboxes on the Exchange Server (local, not cloud).  In a nutshell, we need to cycle through all the mailboxes on the server and pull all the Conversation History folder items and stream these onwards in the process for archiving.  We are using the Java EWS API.  Is is possible to do this?  I have seen some posts that indicate that it should be.  Assuming it is possible, what classes are needed?  Any example code around?  There may be issues around the user id, any information on the privileges required to do this?   This is very general, but all I have at present.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EWS is a Mailbox API so searches are always in the Mailbox context so you can search all mailboxes on a server but you will still need to do it mailbox by mailbox (or folder by folder). For what your trying to do EWS impersonation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/impersonation-and-ews-in-exchange is probably the best option as you only need to set this once and it will work on all mailboxes (including those that get newly created).